# Count IP addresses

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I stored the following IPs in an array:

```
10.2.3.1
10.2.3.5
10.2.3.10 - 10.2.3.15
```

I'm trying to count the total number of IP addresses. The total number of IP addresses should be 8. When I iterate through the array, I get a total of three counts. I need a way to count the third item:

```
10.2.3.10 - 10.2.3.15
```

Are there any IP address counters?

Comment: Neither of those is a valid ruby object. They must be stored in some other format (class). What exactly have you saved in an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to convert an IP to a range, you'll need a function that converts an IPv4 value to an integer, then do math on those:

```
require 'ipaddr'

def ip(string)
  IPAddr.new(string).to_i
end

def parse_ip(string)
  string.split(/\s+\-\s+/).collect { |v| ip(v) }
end

def ip_range(string)
  ips = parse_ip(string)

  ips.last - ips.first + 1
end

ip_range("10.2.3.10 - 10.2.3.15")
# => 6
```

That should do it.

Comment: Note that IPAddr is built into Ruby. It'd do you well to scan through the core and standard libraries of classes that come with Ruby to become familiar with what is available. Actually, scan them them multiple times as there's a lot available so having a nagging feeling you saw it somewhere in one or the other will help in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfect sense to use the `IPAddr` class, as @tadman did, but it should be noted that the methods in that class are not doing anything very special. @tadman's answer works just fine if his method `ip` (the only one to use an `IPAddr` method) is replaced with:

```
def ip(str)
  str.split('.').map { |s| s.to_i.to_s(2).rjust(8,'0') }.join.to_i(2)
end
```

Let's compare:

```
require 'ipaddr'

def tadip(string)
  IPAddr.new(string).to_i
end

str = "10.2.3.10"
tadip str #=> 167904010 
ip    str #=> 167904010 

str = "255.255.255.255"
tadip str #=> 4294967295 
ip    str #=> 4294967295 

str = "172.0.254.1"
tadip str #=> 2885746177 
ip    str #=> 2885746177
```

In fact, `ip`, unlike `IPAddr::new` works for IPv6 (`32**2` bits) as well as IPv4 (`32` bits) IP's (-:

```
str = "172.0.254.1.22.33.44.55"
tadip str #=> IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
ip    str #=> 12394185455143300151
```

Answer (score 0):

to count interval between two IP without ipaddr library :)

```rb
int32start = "10.0.0.0".split(".").map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('N')[0]
int32ending = "10.0.0.50".split(".").map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('N')[0]
puts int32ending - int32start #50
```