# Extracting individual IP addresses

Tags: ruby, ip-address

How can I extract each individual IP address from the array below?

```
strList = ["10.5.5.5 - 10.5.5.8"]
```

The end result should look like this:

```
newList = ["10.5.5.5","10.5.5.6","10.5.5.7","10.5.5.8"]
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: That's not a question. Show us a method you wrote and we'll tell you what can be improved

Comment: Better, but there still are problems. `strList` is an array containing one string. Better, imo, is to say something like, "generate all addresses from "10.5.5.5" to "10.5.5.8", inclusive. The "end result" is four strings, which is not a Ruby object. You should make that an array of four strings. Those changes will stop the downvotes, maybe have some withdrawn. I'll delete this comment when you've seen it.

Comment: How is this question significantly different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650295/count-ip-addresses? Please don't ask the same question or ones that are very similar. Instead, work through the answers supplied and adopt that information to your own code. You don't show any code you've written toward solving this problem. Please do so instead of asking us to write it for you.

Comment: Okay guys, I'm sorry for upsetting most of you; I'm new to StackOverFlow. I'll try to do a better job explaining my question next time. I've re-edited my question, so I hope this is more helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: I know you're new to SO, but one of the rules is that after posting, you can edit to clarify, but you should not change the question. I'm afraid you've done that by adding the file operations. You can see the reason for that: it can render existing answers incomplete or wrong. When you have some time, have a look at the [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: And @CarySwoveland, I've switched my question back to original; sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
require 'ipaddr'

(IPAddr.new("10.5.5.5")..IPAddr.new("10.5.5.8")).map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["10.5.5.5", "10.5.5.6", "10.5.5.7", "10.5.5.8]
```